# WinINet FtpFindFirstFile PInvokeStackImbalance

Tags: .net, vb.net, ftp, wininet

**The Problem:**
When making a managed call to an unmanaged function (in this case, FtpFindFirstFile), I receive a **PInvokeStackImbalance** exception.

**What I Am Trying To Do:**
I'm trying to check for the existence of a file on a FTP server, which led me to using FtpFindFirstFile as a method to achieve this. I successfully use other functionality of the wininet.dll library, but I am unsuccessful with the aforementioned function.

**What I Have Tried So Far:**
Changing the data types of my managed call to match that of the dll call. I have also used GetType() as a method to ensure I really do have the data type I think I have, as the exception message implies I am passing data incorrectly to the parameters of the function. See image, all of those boolean variables return true.

[image: UnbalancedStackError]

**A Call To IsRemoteFileExist():**
The following is a call to my work in progress function IsRemoteFileExist(), this is the function that calls FtpFindFirstFile().

```
    Public Function WindowsTransferFile(arr_sSourceFiles As String(),
                                    sDirTarget As String,
                                    Optional bUploadTransfer As Boolean = False) As Boolean
    'TODO: check for file existence before upload or download
    'TODO: This needs a logic cleanup to accommodate downloading
    Dim bReturn As Boolean = False

    Dim nINet As Long
    Dim nINetConnection As Long

    Dim sTargetFileName As String

    Dim iFileTotalCount As Integer = arr_sSourceFiles.Count
    Dim lstFilesFailed As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)

    Try
        nINet = WinINet.InternetOpen("ftp_sync", WinINet.INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)

        nINetConnection = WinINet.InternetConnect(nINet,
                                                  Me._sHostname,
                                                  21,
                                                  Me._sUsername,
                                                  Me._sPassword,
                                                  WinINet.INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP,
                                                  WinINet.INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE,
                                                  0)

        If nINetConnection = Nothing Then
            Throw New Exception("Connection Failed.") 'TODO: Detailed exception message..
        End If

        ConsoleFeedback.OutputToConsole("Beginning FTP transfer of " & iFileTotalCount.ToString() & " files.")

        For Each sFile As String In arr_sSourceFiles

            If bUploadTransfer Then
                sTargetFileName = sDirTarget & IO.Path.GetFileName(sFile)

                IsRemoteFileExist(sTargetFileName, nINetConnection)

                bReturn = UploadFile(nINetConnection, sFile, sTargetFileName, WinINet.INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0)

                If Not bReturn Then
                    lstFilesFailed.Add(sTargetFileName)
                End If
            Else
                bReturn = DownloadFile(nINetConnection, sFile, sDirTarget, False, 0, WinINet.INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0)
            End If
        Next

        If lstFilesFailed.Count > 0 Then
            Dim sErrorMsg As String = "Finished with failures: "

            For Each sFileFailed As String In lstFilesFailed
                sErrorMsg &= sFileFailed & vbCrLf
            Next

            ConsoleFeedback.OutputToConsole(sErrorMsg)
        Else
            ConsoleFeedback.OutputToConsole("Finished transferring files.")
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message, ex)
    Finally
        WinINet.InternetCloseHandle(CInt(nINet))
    End Try

    Return bReturn
End Function
```

**Definitions Of WinINet.DLL Functions**
Here is a paste to my WinINet function declarations.
[WinINet Function Declarations](https://pastebin.com/GW429yi7)

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Public Class WinINet

   Public Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG = 0 ' // use registry configuration
    Public Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT = 1 ' // direct to net
    Public Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY = 3 ' // via named proxy
    Public Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG_WITH_NO_AUTOPROXY = 4 ' // prevent using java/script/INS

    Public Const INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP = 1       '
    Public Const INTERNET_SERVICE_GOPHER = 2    'Type of service to access.
    Public Const INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP = 3      '

    Public Const INTERNET_OPTION_VERSION = 40   'Returns the version number of Wininet.dll.
    Public Const INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT = 21 'Number of the TCP/IP port on the server to connect to.
    Public Const INTERNET_DEFAULT_GOPHER_PORT = 70
    Public Const INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT = 80
    Public Const INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT = 443
    Public Const INTERNET_DEFAULT_SOCKS_PORT = 1080

    Public Const INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE As Long = &H8000000
    Public Const INTERNET_FLAG_EXISITING_CONNECT As Long = &H20000000
    Public Const INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD As Long = &H80000000 'read from wire even if locally cached
    Public Const INTERNET_FLAG_ASYNC As Long = &H10000000  'this request is asynchronous (where supported)

    Public Structure FILETIME
        Dim dwLowDateTime As Long
        Dim dwHighDateTime As Long
    End Structure

    <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto)>
    Structure WIN32_FIND_DATA
        Public dwFileAttributes As UInteger
        Public ftCreationTime As ComTypes.FILETIME
        Public ftLastAccessTime As ComTypes.FILETIME
        Public ftLastWriteTime As ComTypes.FILETIME
        Public nFileSizeHigh As UInteger
        Public nFileSizeLow As UInteger
        Public dwReserved0 As UInteger
        Public dwReserved1 As UInteger
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=260)> Public cFileName As String
        <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst:=14)> Public cAlternateFileName As String
    End Structure

    Public Declare Function internetopen Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetOpenA" (ByVal lpszAgent As String, ByVal dwAccessType As Long, ByVal lpszproxyName As String, ByVal lpszproxyBypass As String, ByVal dwflags As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function InternetCloseHandle Lib "wininet.dll" (ByVal HINet As Integer) As Integer
    Public Declare Function InternetOpen Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetOpenA" (ByVal sAgent As String, ByVal lAccessType As Integer, ByVal sProxyName As String, ByVal sProxyBypass As String, ByVal lFlags As Integer) As Integer
    Public Declare Function InternetConnect Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetConnectA" (ByVal hInternetSession As Integer, ByVal sServerName As String, ByVal nServerPort As Integer, ByVal sUsername As String, ByVal sPassword As String, ByVal lService As Integer, ByVal lFlags As Integer, ByVal lContext As Integer) As Integer
    Public Declare Function FtpGetFile Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "FtpGetFileA" (ByVal hFtpSession As Integer, ByVal lpszRemoteFile As String, ByVal lpszNewFile As String, ByVal fFailIfExists As Boolean, ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Integer, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dwContext As Integer) As Boolean
    Public Declare Function FtpPutFile Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "FtpPutFileA" (ByVal hFtpSession As Integer, ByVal lpszLocalFile As String, ByVal lpszRemoteFile As String, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dwContext As Integer) As Boolean
    Public Declare Function FtpFindFirstFile Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "FtpFindFirstFileA" (ByVal hFtpSession As IntPtr, ByVal lpszSearchFile As String, ByVal lpFindFileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dwContext As IntPtr) As IntPtr
    Public Declare Function InternetFindNextFile Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetFindNextFileA" (ByVal hFind As Long, ByVal lpFindFileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA) As Long
    Public Declare Function FtpSetCurrentDirectory Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "FtpSetCurrentDirectoryA" (ByVal hFtpSession As Long, ByVal lpszDirectory As String) As Boolean
    Public Declare Function FtpGetCurrentDirectory Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "FtpGetCurrentDirectoryA" (ByVal hFtpSession As Long, ByVal lpszCurrentDirectory As String, ByVal lpdwCurrentDirectory As Long) As Long
    Public Declare Function FtpFindFirstFile Lib "WinInet" Alias "FtpFindFirstFileA" (ByVal hFtp As Long, ByVal lpszSearchFile As String, lpFindFileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwContext As Long) As Long

End Class
```

Not sure how else to proceed on this one, all the other WinINet functionality works for me, it's just this one that I am having trouble with.

**Edit**
Just noticed that the lib was "WinINet", I changed it to "wininet.dll" for consistency.

Old Declaration:

```
Public Declare Function FtpFindFirstFile Lib "WinInet" Alias "FtpFindFirstFileA" (ByVal hFtp As Long, ByVal lpszSearchFile As String, lpFindFileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwContext As Long) As Long <br>
```

New Declaration:

```
Public Declare Function FtpFindFirstFile Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "FtpFindFirstFileA" (ByVal hFtp As Long, ByVal lpszSearchFile As String, lpFindFileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwContext As Long) As Long <br>
```

Of course, that did not fix my problem though.

Comment: A Win32 Long would be a NET Int32, but the first handle argument could well be an IntPtr.  You probably have similar issues with all those UInts in the FindData structure.  The VB6 style declaration should also be changed to a NET DLLimport version.

Comment: I have tried changing the first parameter to IntPtr data type and had no success.

Comment: **All** those `Long` params would be wrong.  `(hCon As IntPtr,  searchFile As String, ByRef findFileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA, Flags As Integer, context As IntPtr) As IntPtr` is probably the correct types

Comment: When there are tons of ways to do FTP on .NET, doing your own PInvoke is the least efficient.

Comment: @LexLi Agreed, do you mind letting me know of some ways I can perform FTP efficiently in vb.net? I have tried WinSCP in the past but I have always had issues with uploading when using it.

Comment: Microsoft has its samples, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/ftp, while open source projects and commercial libraries are all over the place. Use Google smartly and you can find them all.

Comment: I'm just going to stick with using WinINet still, I tried other avenues per your suggestion like WebRequest and WebClient but without fail it always hangs on the second upload whether it is synchronous or asynchronous.

I'm getting the most stability out of wininet, I will just have to update and query a database column to determine whether or not the file was uploaded already, rather than trying to see if the file exists on the remote server.. sad way to do it but I can't figure this out unfortunately.

Comment: The WIN32_FIND_DATA argument must be ByRef and requires the `<Out>` attribute.

Comment: @HansPassant That fixed the problem, please put this as the answer so I can accept it. Thank you.. Such a stupid oversight, sadly I think that was a copy paste from microsoft's API documentation.